# Port forwarding issue - Connection refused when SSHing into a configured port

Tags: router, ssh, ip, port-forwarding, isp

### Foreword

- I do have an public IP, which I can verify on [WhatIsMyIPAddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/);
- When I try to connect to my computer from the outside via any of these

  ```
  ssh myusername@mypublicIP
  ssh -p 22 myusername@mypublicIP
  ssh -p 2222 myusername@mypublicIP
  ...
  ```

  I see no output for a while and, eventually, I get this error

  ```
  ssh: connect to host mypublicIP port 2222: Connection timed out
  ```

  This is expected, I believe, as I've not configured the port forwarding yet (for any port).

### My attempt to configure port forwarding for SSH

So I proceed to try configuring it in my router's config page¹.

The router config page allows doing so via two interfaces: *SIMPLIFIED PORT MAPPING* and *PORT MAPPING*, but with neither of them do I have success:

- When I try via *PORT MAPPING*, as soon as I set the *Internal port* to 22, I see the following error, and the *Add* button becomes greyed out, so I can't finalize the setting

> *The selected port is not available, as it is currently used for interior of your FASTGate services.*

[image]

- When I try via *SIMPLIFIED PORT MAPPING*, I successfully finalize the setting (I just have to select *SSH on port 2222 in/out* and my computer from a dropdown menu, and hit *Add*, but when I try `ssh`ing into my machine from the outside, I get

  ```
  $ ssh -p 2222 myusername@mypublicIP
  ssh: connect to host mypublicIP port 2222: Connection refused
  ```

  which tells me that the configuration I've done *is* having some effect, because I get a `refused` error instead of `timed out`, but something is still not quite right.
  [image]

---

Fwiw, my router is from my provider (I'm in Italy), [FastWeb](https://www.fastweb.it/myfastweb/assistenza/guide/FASTGate/).

Comment: Your description seems incomplete – which external port to which internal port did you end up configuring in the router? And which ports did you configure sshd to listen on? E.g. you're trying to connect to port 2222, but under "PORT MAPPING" you don't mention actually trying to add a rule for it.

Comment: @user1686, under "SIMPLIFIED PORT MAPPING", I can't configure ports myself; the only possible alternative is _SSH on port 2222 in/out_ (there was a typo in the question), which I suspect means that the external port is 2222 and the internal port is the SSH port which is 22. Under "PORT MAPPING", as soon as I put 22 for the internal port (there was a typo in the question), the button to confirm becomes greyed out, whatever I fill the other fields with, so I simply can't add the rule.

Comment: @user1686, I've also added a couple of screenshots.

Comment: Is your SSH server internally reachable on port 2222? If it isn’t, this cannot work.

Comment: @DanielB, do you mean doing `ssh -p 2222 myusername@mypublicIPaddress` from my own computer? If this is what you mean, I get `Connection refused` regardless of whether I set up the simplified port forwarding or not.

Comment: No, I meant internally. That means using the host’s (“Fisso”?) internal IP address.

Comment: @DanielB, `ssh myusername@192.168.1.100` (without specifying a port) works.

Comment: as @DanielB writes you need to start the ssh service on your computer to 2222 port instead of 22.

Comment: @krg, really? Then what if I want to use a different port for different IPs? I still have my old `.ssh/config` in a laptop where I had set `Port 9022` and `Port 9122` for connecting to my computer (the one in the question) if it was connected via Ethernet or WiFi respectively. And it all worked. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean...?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question. The standard port of ssh is 22. But your router wants port 2222. You need to open ssh on IP: 192.168.1.100 (computer) and port: 2222. You did it on your router. But on your computer you still running at port 22. As you wrote above `ssh user@ip` works. `.ssh/config` is for the client not for the server!

Comment: @krg, Yes, `.ssh/config` in for the client. And I have a client (my laptop) still configured with `Port 9022` for my computer when it's connected via Eth and `Port 9122` for my computer when it's connected via WiFi. And as far as I remember this port configuration was done only from the router config page: `publicIP`+`port 9022` -> `localIPviaEth`+`port 22`, and `publicIP`+`port 9122` -> `localIPviaWiFi`+`port 22`, iirc. Are you implying I need to do something non via router config page?

Comment: You opened 2222 port or 9022 + 9122? I thought we are talking about port 2222. I ignore ports 9022 + 9122. I don't understand why you mention those ports. Neither your computer, neither your router are "listening" to those ports. Sorry I don't understand how you can connect with ports 9022 + 9122 and you can't with 2222.

Comment: @krg _I have my client **still** configured [...]_ means that **once upon a time** port forwarding was working, and i could actually forward two ports to two IPs. Now it's not working. Is it clear?

Comment: Ok, but it's clear that your computer [listens to port 22] (https://superuser.com/questions/1662920/port-forwarding-issue-connection-refused-when-sshing-into-a-configured-port?noredirect=1#comment2548564_1662920) and you expect to listen with 2222. So, why you just don't change the port to 2222?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked for help on archlinux' IRC channel.

The outcome of the investigation was that something is wrong with my router, which doesn't allow me to forward *to* port 22 via the "normal" port mapping interface, as the first screenshot in the question shows.

To fix this, it seems I have two options:

- try hard-resetting the router to see if it will then allow me to set 22 as the internal port during port mapping,
- call the ISP, FastWeb, to ask help.

Probably the first option is the easiest to try, given the (statistically) scarce knowledge of the technical people at FastWeb, but probably also the least likely to have an impact; after all, I've not done any harm to the router, and, as far as I can tell based on my memory, the issue started precisely after a hard-reset of the router.

To work around the problem for now, I had to

- set `Port 2222` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so that my computer, as the SSH server, listens on port `2222` (to which I can forward) instead of `22` (to which I can't for the router is stupid),
- set up port forwarding from external port `wxyz` to internal port `2222`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have enough reputation in this community in order to add a simple comment, so I have to resort to a fully-fledged answer. I am Italian too and have the same modem & issue, and I can provide more certainty about the fact that the

> - try hard-resetting the router to see if it will then allow me to set 22 as the internal port during port mapping

option would not work. For Italian readers, [this](https://spectrum.chat/indomus/home-assistant/port-forwarding-fastgate%7E4970f57c-c4b2-4ba0-bfa8-47a8ae05284f) seems to prove that this modem features such a bug since early 2020, due to a firmware update.

Thank you Enrico for your self-answer, I was becoming insane trying to solve this!

---

Edit:

In order to try and forget about this issue, I also created a `config` file inside `~/.ssh`, at every SSH client I am planning to use, that contains:

```
Host raspberry_at_home
    HostName 192.168.1.17
    Port 2222
    User andrea

Host raspberry_when_outside
    HostName <MY_PUBLIC_IP>
    Port 2222
    User andrea
```

so that I can also connect locally without having to specify each time a different port than the default `22` (i.e., the imposed `2222`).
For instance, I now can just run:

```
ssh raspberry_when_outside
```

All of this said, if I understood the issue correctly, this bug in our modem will not allow anyone to connect to more than 1 SSH server inside the same LAN (from outside the network), as it only allows to use the predetermined `2222` port for the task, to which you can of course bind a single local IP address: this is 100% true if all is done with the "simplified"/tailored configuration provided by Fastweb. I still did not fully understand what @Enlico meant with

> - set up port forwarding from external port `wxyz` to internal port `2222`

But I still managed to solve my issue without that step.

Hope this may help someone in the future (maybe Technicolor employees too)!

---

### TL;DR

- Use the simplified Port Mapping SSH configuration provided by the Modem
- (As @Enlico said) *"Set Port `2222` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so that my computer, as the SSH server, listens on port `2222` (to which I can forward) instead of `22` (to which I can't for the router is stupid)"*
- Optionally, create `~/.ssh/config` and customize the file as suggested above

Comment: Thank you very much, happy to see that somebody confirms what I've observed.

Comment: Thanks to you for saving me a bunch of hours! :)

Answer (score 0):

SSH is not going to accept the connecton if it sees you coming in on port 2222 and it's probably listing on port 22.
You can check with `sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep sshd` on which port ssh is accepting connections. (on the machine where you are connecting to with ssh)

You can change the SSH ports using these commands:

```
sudo sed -i "s/#Port 22/Port 2222/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```